# how to connect arduino like board to ROS2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was using rosserial for comunicating arduino like boards (custom made STM32F722 in fact) on ROS1
Now I'm starting to use ROS2 and need something like rosserial.

Thank

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375980/how-to-connect-arduino-like-board-to-ros2/) by [elgarbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/32969/elgarbe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2021-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like what [Micro-ROS](https://micro.ros.org) was created for.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0